# How to group all sequently ordered elements with the same class seperated by divider classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, siblings

I have a list which consists of list dividers and items. I want to order items underneath a list divider alphabetically, one by one. Before I can do this, I need those to be grouped. The problem is that those are not ordened within a `div`, but those are on the same level. I have tried a lot but cannot find out how to group those in an array sothat I am able to loop through the groups.

The html structure I have is the following:

```
<div class="list">
 <div class="list-divider">A list divider</div>
 <div class="element">A</div>
 <div class="element">B</div>
 <div class="list-divider">A list divider</div>
 <div class="element">G</div>
 <div class="element">A</div>
 <div class="element">C</div>
 <div class="element">B</div>
 <div class="list-divider">A list divider</div>
 <div class="element">A</div>
 <div class="element">X</div>
 <div class="element">X</div>
 <div class="element">C</div>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to group those into an array?

Comment: For the list dividers you have a closing `</p>` instead of a closing `</div>` is this by mistake?

Comment: Yea, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres what I was able to come up with:

```js
var sortable = [];
var newHTML = "";

$(".list > div").each(function(key, value) {
  if (value.className == "list-divider"){
   sortable.push([]);
  }
  else {
   sortable[sortable.length-1].push(value);
  }
})
for (i in sortable)
{
  sortable[i].sort(function(a,b) {return (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML) ? 1 : ((b.innerHTML > a.innerHTML) ? -1 : 0);} );
}
$(".list > .list-divider").each(function(key, value) {
  newHTML += value.outerHTML;
  for (i in sortable[key])
   newHTML += sortable[key][i].outerHTML;
})
$(".list").html(newHTML)
```

[Here is a link to my code](http://jsfiddle.net/pu5sq3dt/36/)